# Does Axis 2 support Java 17?

Tags: java, apache-axis, java-17, wsdl2java

I get the following error while using Axis 2 with Java 17. Previously, I was using Java 8. It was all good. During this migration (from Java 8 to Java 17) I getg this error. Can any one help me here on how to proceed further or any suggestions.

```
error: cannot access DataHandler
class file for javax.activation.DataHandler not found
```

Comment: You're missing a dependency on javax-activation/jakarta-activation version 1.x (do not use 2.x or higher, as that will use the new package namespace `jakarta.activation` instead of `javax.activation`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark Rotteveel
 Axis2 is using same namespace as javax.activation which was present in java8  but now that has been removed from jdk 17  that's  what causing the issue i feel 
in this case how to proceed is my question 

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add the javax-activation or jakarta-activation library with a 1.x version (I believe 1.2 is the latest 1.x).